# Why Is Firebase-admin Not returning the Documents but a different object in express

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore

I Am trying to create a node wrapper around my firebase function on a different server
technically using firebase as my main Database

And anytime I try to read using the default query function in the doc

```
const db = firebase-admin.firestore()
const data = await db.collection("cities").get()
```

Now instead of getting an array of objects like this

```
"_query": {
            "_firestore": {
                "projectId": "fir-demo-jd1"
            },
            "_queryOptions": {
                "parentPath": {
                    "segments": []
                },
                "collectionId": "bets",
                "converter": {},
                "allDescendants": false,
                "fieldFilters": [
                ],
                "fieldOrders": [
                ],
                "limit": null,
                "limitType": 0,
                "kindless": false,
                "requireConsistency": true
            },
            "_serializer": {
                "allowUndefined": false
            },
            "_allowUndefined": false
        },
        "_readTime": {
            "_seconds": 1676797103,
            "_nanoseconds": 433061000
        },
        "_size": 2,
        "_materializedDocs": null,
        "_materializedChanges": null
    },
```

What I want is to be able to see the list of country alone

As I woud later to use paganation also on the `data` thats like

`.limit()` with ease

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Apartly I have to map and convert it to JSON using this function

```
const db = firebase-admin.firestore()
const data = await db.collection("cities").get()
console.log(docs.map((doc)=>doc.data()))
```

I thought firebase handled all this under the hood

Answer (score 0):

`db.collection("cities").get()` returns a `QuerySnapshot` and from there you can loop over the `DocumentSnapshot`s, as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#web-version-8_7):

```
const querySnapshot = await db.collection("cities").get();
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```